# What does Sacred Bell do?

Tags: pokemon-tabletop-united

The Pokémon Bronzong has the High Ability called "Sacred Bell". However, I can not find this ability anywhere within the core rule book. Where can I find the details about this ability, and what does it do?

Comment: tbh, I don't know anything about the tabletop, but I thought that "sacred bell" was a descriptor for the actual pokemon, not an ability.

Comment: It is listed as its "Higher Ability", which it gains at lvl 40.

Answer (score 2):

### It was seemingly added in an errata / playtest pack. It makes Bronzong resist Dark and Ghost-Type moves one step further

It can at least be found in the February 2016 errata / playtest packet which is inside the zip file found under "Download PTU 1.05 here" from [the official website](https://pokemontabletop.com/downloads-and-resources/). The errata states:

> [...] **Ability: Sacred Bell**
>
> Static
>
> **Effect:** The user resists Dark and Ghost-Type Damage one step further. [...]

Notably, Bronzong is Steel/Psychic so it would ordinarily be hit super effectively by Dark and Ghost-Type Moves; this ability causes them to hit with neutral effectiveness.

This was the earliest mention of the Ability I found, though perhaps an earlier version of it exists somewhere also. Note that this errata is a playtest pack; to quote its opening:

> This is a supplementary playtest document for the fanmade Pokémon Tabletop United roleplaying system, written for use with the 1.05 release version of PTU.
>
> We’ll occasionally release packets like this one to test experimental content and give us a sandbox to play with ideas that aren’t quite ready for a full release but which we want to get feedback and comments on. Everything you see here is subject to change!

This included quite a few changes besides just the apparent addition of the Sacred Bell Ability, such as completely altering how the Flinched Affliction works.